# removing null valued columns from dataset in asp .net

Tags: dataset

I have a table which stores data with null valued columns for some entries .I want to retrieve only Not null data to the detail view. I tried the following

```
foreach(string strTableField in (objDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[i])) 
{
    if(objDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[i].Equals(null))
    {
        objDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(strTableField);
       objDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    }

    i++;
}
```

but it is giving error .. Pls help me reg this ...

Comment: What error message are you recieving?

Comment: If it's data from sql database, you can try to check for DBNull.Value.

Comment: Mark answer as accepted if it resolve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method of DataSet class. Like this:

```
DataRow[] rows = table.Select("field is not null");
```